# find() not working in C++ Header

Tags: c++, vector, find

I have a vector in my Header file, and I'm trying to do a bool function that returns the find() function, but it is giving me an error.

```
vector<string> reservedWord{
....
....
....
};
```

bool function

```
bool isReservedWord(string str)
{
   return find(reservedWord.begin(), reservedWord.end(), str) != reservedWord.end();
}
```

I tried it both without the last `!= reservedWord.end)` and also without.

The errors given are these:

```
||=== Build: Release in compilers (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
E:\University\compilers\reservedWords.h||In function 'bool isReservedWord(std::string)':|
E:\University\compilers\reservedWords.h|40|error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >::iterator, std::string&)'|
E:\University\compilers\reservedWords.h|40|note: candidate is:|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\streambuf_iterator.h|371|note: template<class _CharT2> typename __gnu_cxx::__enable_if<std::__is_char<_CharT2>::__value, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> > >::__type std::find(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >, const _CharT2&)|
c:\program files (x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\include\c++\bits\streambuf_iterator.h|371|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
E:\University\compilers\reservedWords.h|40|note:   '__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<std::basic_string<char>*, std::vector<std::basic_string<char> > >' is not derived from 'std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT2, std::char_traits<_CharT> >'|
E:\University\compilers\reservedWords.h|41|warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

Comment: Did you include the appropriate header files? An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is much more helpful than bits of code.

Comment: @chris I imported <vector> and also <string> just in case

Comment: You need <algorithm> for find

Comment: I just noticed now mate that i need <algorithm> Thanks all for your help (stupid me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example.  Look at how your code is different.  Ask questions as required.  :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<std::string> g_reserved
{
    "the",
    "quick", 
    "brown", 
    "fox", 
    "jumps", 
    "over",
    "the",
    "lazy",
    "dog"
};

bool IsReserved(const std::string &s)
{
    return g_reserved.end() !=
           std::find(g_reserved.cbegin(), g_reserved.cend(), s);
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << std::boolalpha
              << IsReserved("fox")
              << ' '
              << IsReserved("zebra")
              << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there a reason why one would prefer using std::string rather than jsut declaring the namespace?

Comment: @DodoSerebro - Yes, it is generally considered bad style to just put `using namespace std;`.  The std namespace contains a very large number of classes and functions and the likelihood of a name clash is rather high.  If you really hate "`std::`", you can import specific objects: "`using std::string;`".  However my personal preference is to just refer to things by their full name.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same compilation error when `<string>` was included but `<algorithm>` was not. In that case the compiler only sees the declaration of

```
std::find(std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, std::istreambuf_iterator<_CharT>, const _CharT2&)
```

and quits with this error.

To fix this, add

```
#include <algorithm>
```